# I solved my own question that was closed and deleted

Tags: discussion, guidelines, deleted-questions

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178829/xelatex-error-with-fontspec

It turns out the same problem happens when you install a lot of new fonts. XeLaTeX takes a while to "load" them or whatever it needs to do, but after you let it run for a few minutes it will successfully compile the document. It only happens the first time you compile a document, everything will work as expected from the second time on.

The same problem happens with the GIMP: if you install new fonts it takes some time to rebuild the font cache and in the while it becomes unresponsive. After that, everything works fine.

The question is now closed and deleted. It seems to me that the question itself may be off topic, but maybe the answer may be useful to someone. What should I do?

Answer (score 7):

The question was automatically deleted - [something that happens to low-activity posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/168244). You have the option of voting to undelete the post (from the [linked answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/168244)):

---

### How can I undelete one of my posts?

Self-deleted posts can be viewed, edited, and undeleted by their original authors.

Note: deleted questions do not appear in search results, so you if you wish to later undelete a question that you've deleted you must have saved the URL somewhere. Users with 10K reputation and up can also mark questions as a "favorite" and find them later from the Favorites tab on their profiles.

If your post was deleted by [trusted users](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user), it will require three undelete votes to be undeleted - politely asking for this on Meta may attract the necessary votes if you make a good case for why the question should be restored.

If your post was deleted by a moderator, you can flag one of your other posts and write a note in the "other" section explaining the situation and requesting undeletion.

---

However, from the likes of it, this doesn't seem like a problem at all. Someone in a similar boat may just wait that little bit longer and not experience the "problem" at all. Reasons for undeleting a post should include a consideration for whether the post (question and answer) would be useful for a broader audience. In my opinion, this is not really the case.

Comment: Wow, marking a question as favourite is a hard-earned privilege... `;)` I guess you meant that everybody can star a question, but only 10k-ers can still view it if it was deleted in the meantime. Which, back to the topic, makes me wonder, what would happen for a non-10k-er in the same situation? Would the question disappear from the starred list altogether, or would the URL still be available, but lead to a 404?

Comment: @T.Verron: I don't know, but that's good question...

Answer (score -2):

I do not have enough reputation to comment on the answer, so I am adding a new answer. (Please help me with a right code of conduct if it is different.)

I do not agree with Werner that it is not a "problem" because someone might wait "little bit longer". "Little bit" is subjective and might change depending on the computer. An advanced user might know this problem and might wait, but an unfamiliar user might just consider it as broken (which I assume every time when something does not respond for several minutes).

So my question is that, should stackoverflow be only for advanced users instead of addressing all the users?

Comment: It's a **little bit** late to comment on this no?

Comment: Does this answer the question though?

Comment: @Werner I am not trying to answer the question. I am trying question your assumption of "no problem at all" could be a serious problem for a beginner. By deleting the question, you are preventing a new user from finding a solution.

Comment: @percusse Is it? Unfortunately, I came across this post 3 years later. But, I do not think this problem is addressed in stackoverflow yet, because I face similar issues even now. So, I think it is not late at all.

Comment: @tokyoCoder: The question was deleted automatically. New users would typically ask a question (even if they've found something similar that didn't help them); that's what this site is for. If the question was already asked before, it'll be references and hopefully closed as a duplicate. If not, hopefully it's written well enough to garner sufficient attention not to be deleted.